# Random multipath power and delay generation

Tags: digital-communications, multipath

I'm trying to simulate an indoor environment that exhibits multipath propagation.

However, I don't know how to generate random multipath variables like path power and path delay (power-delay profile). I found a paper in [here](http://www.academia.edu/13861172/Multipath_Rayleigh_and_Rician_Fading_Channel_Simulation_Using_MATLAB) and I think this was the one I am looking for but I have a hard time understanding it.

For example: which distribution should be used for randoming other paths' power and delay values? Is it viable for indoors or is there a better approach for indoors?

Edit:

Example in code:

```
rayChan = comm.RayleighChannel('SampleRate',100000,'MaximumDopplerShift',130,...
'PathDelays',[0 a b],'AveragePathGains',[0, t1, t2],...
'Visualization','Impulse response');
```

In the code I want to randomize a,b,t1 and t2 values. In the article I provided above has expected value of some number of paths and they think it is realistic but I couldn't find which distribution they used to determine each path delays and avarage path gains.

Comment: Your document is a succint version of (before R2016) Matlab documentations of Fading channel object https://fr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/fading-channels.html#a1070375923. If you want to understand more deeply, follow the link with some cited documents. Please ask more specific question. For your example question, with the classic assumption indoor = rich scattering, no dominant path, and low velocity, Rayleigh distribution FIR channel model is widely used.

Comment: I am not looking for a distribution for fading. I am looking for a distribution to randomize the path delays and average path gains.

Comment: Do you mean that in your model, your **physical** paths are finite and well-identified ? Or you know exactly you have $n$, say $n=5$ for example, physcial paths and you want to have the distribution of gains and delays of these $n$ paths ? If it is the case, sorry it is out of my knowledge.

Comment: It's the second case and it's okay. Guess we will learn together :)

Comment: I talked about only one model that physical paths are identified for indoor environment. Lets wait for interesting answers.